# Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths

Tags: android

Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.

> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
> > Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.InputParameterUtils.prepareInputParameterValue(InputParameterUtils.java:33)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.lambda$visitRegularInputs$1(TaskExecution.java:315)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:106)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitRegularInputs(TaskExecution.java:315)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter.fingerprintInputProperties(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateWithOutputs(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:193)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionState$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:141)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:130)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:239)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:230)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:126)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ProviderResolutionStrategy$1.resolve(ProviderResolutionStrategy.java:27)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.DeferredUtil.unpack(DeferredUtil.java:59)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.DeferredUtil.unpackOrNull(DeferredUtil.java:49)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.InputParameterUtils.prepareInputParameterValue(InputParameterUtils.java:39)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.InputParameterUtils.prepareInputParameterValue(InputParameterUtils.java:31)
  ... 68 more
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.lambda$beforeRead$0(TransformBackedProvider.java:84)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.BuildableBackedProvider$1.visitProducerTasks(BuildableBackedProvider.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueSupplier$ValueProducer.visitContentProducerTasks(ValueSupplier.java:59)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.beforeRead(TransformBackedProvider.java:81)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.collectEntries(Collectors.java:216)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.calculateValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:337)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.finalValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:189)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.finalValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:37)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:236)
  ... 76 more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Can you please upgrade dependency in build.gradle(project level dependancy)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' to
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

this step worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

i have solved the issue i go in build.gradle(project) then change my gradle tool version with my previous **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'**
and also change in gradle-wrapper-properties from 7.5 to 7.3.3

now its working ^^ thanks to Nate who helped me

Comment: That's great. So, the issue was still modifying the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:` classpath. I have learnt to always change version numbers until I get the version that works

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Firebase Google Services.
If you upgraded gradle before getting the error, you will have to downgrade to the previous working version.

For me, I downgraded to `7.1.1` in `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`. In the dependencies object, change the version number of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.x.x` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1`.

Then, go to `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.x.x-all.zip` on line 3 to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`.

**Note: The version numbers I used are the previous versions that worked for me. You will have to versions that initially worked for you.**

Comment: Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4. Current version is 7.1.1.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Change Gradle version in Gradle wrapper to 7.4 and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle Settings.

Comment: Are you getting this as an error or a warning?

Comment: its a error please help me

Comment: Are you working with Java, Kotlin, React Native, Flutter?
PS: I don't often receive SO notifications early enough. If you have not fixed it and have a means we can communicate faster, preferrably Telegram username, kindly share

Comment: i am working using java i added plugin which was required jdk 11 and gradle version 7.5 now but its only error app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: I think the issue still lies in `com.android.tools.build:gradle` classpath. Since `7.1.1` did not work for you, try a higher version.

Comment: if i can go till 7.0.3 last  more higher it will gives error again